# DynamoDB for ServiceStack 4.0.48

Tags: servicestack, amazon-dynamodb

In my experience working with DynamoDB and its provisioned throughput, the limits often are hit in normal usage. To work around this, I have used retry approaches such as [Polly](http://www.hanselman.com/blog/NuGetPackageOfTheWeekPollyWannaFluentlyExpressTransientExceptionHandlingPoliciesInNET.aspx) transient exception handling to simplify retry logic.

Does anyone know if there is any mechanism in ServiceStack to account for DynamoDB throughput limits in the current release of ServiceStack.AWS?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Yes all [PocoDynamo](https://github.com/ServiceStack/PocoDynamo) API's are [executed within a managed context](https://github.com/ServiceStack/ServiceStack.Aws/blob/743243d0afff483a2ef3c249d4066fb8e8e85989/src/ServiceStack.Aws/DynamoDb/PocoDynamo.Support.cs#L39) where temporary errors are automatically retried using [Amazons recommended exponential backoff](http://docs.aws.amazon.com/amazondynamodb/latest/developerguide/ErrorHandling.html#APIRetries).

The retry Exception Types are defined on [PocoDynamo client](https://github.com/ServiceStack/ServiceStack.Aws/blob/743243d0afff483a2ef3c249d4066fb8e8e85989/src/ServiceStack.Aws/DynamoDb/PocoDynamo.cs#L64-L69) which defaults to:

```
RetryOnErrorCodes = new HashSet<string> {
    "ThrottlingException",
    "ProvisionedThroughputExceededException",
    "LimitExceededException",
    "ResourceInUseException",
};
```